# java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to be able to connect a program of mine to a database. But since I have never worked with databases before I am following a tutorial found here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/03/springboot-working-jdbctemplate.html. After following all the steps (to the best of my knowledge) of the tutorial I get the following stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@34a245ab;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@34a245ab
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:283) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:716) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:648) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.4.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46) [spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:176) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:77) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:62) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at edu.demo.SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.main(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
```

Is anyone familiar with this type of error? It's probably something pretty simple. The IDE I am using is IntelliJ. I have put my code below:

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
    package edu.demo;

    public class User{
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String email;

    public User(int number, String strName, String strEmail){
        id = number;
        name = strName;
        email = strEmail;
    }

    public User(){

    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**SpringbootJdbcDemoApplicationTests.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.*;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.class)
public class SpringbootJdbcDemoApplicationTests {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @org.junit.Test
        public void findAllUsers() {
                List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
                Assert.assertNotNull(users);
                Assert.assertTrue(!users.isEmpty());
        }

        @Test
        public void findUserById() {
                User user = userRepository.findUserById(1);
                Assert.assertNotNull(user);
        }

        @Test
        public void createUser() {
                User user = new User(0, "John", "john@gmail.com");
                User savedUser = userRepository.create(user);
                User newUser = userRepository.findUserById(savedUser.getId());
                Assert.assertNotNull(newUser);
                Assert.assertEquals("John", newUser.getName());
                Assert.assertEquals("john@gmail.com", newUser.getEmail());
        }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package edu.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.*;

@org.junit.runner.RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SpringbootJdbcDemoApplication.class)
public class SpringbootJdbcDemoApplicationTests {
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @org.junit.Test
        public void findAllUsers() {
                List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
                Assert.assertNotNull(users);
                Assert.assertTrue(!users.isEmpty());
        }

        @Test
        public void findUserById() {
                User user = userRepository.findUserById(1);
                Assert.assertNotNull(user);
        }

        @Test
        public void createUser() {
                User user = new User(0, "John", "john@gmail.com");
                User savedUser = userRepository.create(user);
                User newUser = userRepository.findUserById(savedUser.getId());
                Assert.assertNotNull(newUser);
                Assert.assertEquals("John", newUser.getName());
                Assert.assertEquals("john@gmail.com", newUser.getEmail());
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh my that's a lot of code! If you take parts of it out, do you still have the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in your pom you have a dependency for `h2` like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and you want to use [mysql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java). Either change it, or simply add mysql if you're also using h2, to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Entering that code in my pom file gives me a new error: " com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Comment: That's really a different question, but now that you have the mysql jdbc driver, you need to configure it to point to your database. That's usually in your [**application.properties**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html). From the link, *DataSource configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in `spring.datasource.*`*, `url`, `username`, `password` and `driver-class-name`.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into the page you linked @Elliott Frisch. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

And my solution：

step1：delete the 'mysql-connector' maven repository：

```
rm -r ~/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java
```

step2：add following snippet into pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

step3：save the project，then wait for the “Building workspace” completely，and all going well. But I don't know what happened...

Answer (score 2):

For folks who are building a datasource manually, besides loading the `mysql-connector-dependency`, ensure that the `driver class name` is set correctly.

```
DataSourceFactory factory = new DataSourceFactory();
factory.setUrl("..");
factory.setUser("..");
factory.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Important
...
DBI dbi = new DBI(factory.build(new MetricRegistry(), "mysql"));
```

Otherwise, `DataSourceFactory.driverClass` instance field gets set to `""`. When the application class loader tries to load a class with a name of `""`, it will throw a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: I also had very similar issue when I was using a dropwizard framework, I was missing configuration with values, so the error was like: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class:  from ClassLoader`

Answer (score 0):

if you work with netbeans and hibernate framwork add jdbc manually go to persistence.xml and go to design add jdbc connection it works fine to me 
good luck